# Compute $\int_0^{x_0}f^\prime(x)$ and $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f^\prime(x)$

Tags: calculus, differential-topology

Suppose $f: S^1 \to S^1$, and $f(x_i) = y$, where $x_i$s are the preimage of a regular value $y$. Then how can I compute
$\int_0^{x_0}f^\prime(x), \int_{x_0}^{x_1}f^\prime(x),$?

I realize that $\operatorname{deg}f|_{[0, x_0]}:= \pm 1$ since there is only 1 preimage point of $y$, namely $x_0$.

I am also aware that $\int_0^{x_0} f^\prime(t)dt = f(x_0) - f(0).$

But then it becomes strange: because $x_i$s are preimages of $y$, then
$\int_0^{x_0}f^\prime(x) = f(x_0) - f(0) = y - f(0)$ and

$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f^\prime(x) = f(x_1) - f(x_0) = y - y =0$?

Comment: Why do you feel that this is strange?

Comment: Hi @JesseMadnick - I believe the value shall be $\pm 1$, or 0. But $\int_0^{x_0}f^\prime(x)$ involves the value of $f(0)$, and all the rest is 0.

Comment: @JesseMadnick $\int_0^1 f^\prime(t)dt = \int_0^{x_0} f^\prime(t)dt + \dots + \int_{x_{n-1}}^1 f^\prime(t)dt$ suppose to produce the degree of $f$.